# why first value is repeated when doing a loop in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have several netcdf files that i want to extract to text file but I found that the first value (from the first file)of `A,B,C`in the output file `es55.txt` is repeated for the whole text file so the loop does not take values from other files
the code:

```
    library("ncdf")
 a<-list.files("C:\\Users\\CLdata", "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)
 dt <-   as.POSIXct(strptime(basename(a), "data_%Y%m%dT%H%M%S_%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", tz = "GMT"))
 for(i in 1:length(a)){
  f <- open.ncdf(a[i])
  A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="Sgf",verbose=TRUE)
  B <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="gh")
  C <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="jk")
  df=data.frame(date = dt, A, B ,C ) }
   write.table(df,file="es55.txt")
```

example:

```
    "date" "A" "B" "C"
    "1" 2010-09-29 23:59:59 0.0191961424604022 216 216
    "2" 2010-09-29 23:59:59 0.0191961424604022 216 216
    "3" 2010-09-29 23:59:59 0.0191961424604022 216 216
    "4" 2010-09-29 23:59:59 0.0191961424604022 216 216
    "5" 2010-09-29 23:59:59 0.0191961424604022 216 216
```

Comment: I think you need a `library` call in there.  Where is `get.var.ncdf` from?

Comment: Are you sure that `es55.txt` contains the data from the *first* file? In your loop, you overwrite `df` each time and only write the file with the last contents of `df`. So I would rather expect that you write the contents of the *last* file (`a[length(a)]`) to `es55.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the fact that you're writing to the file outside of the loop. Try to append to the file inside of the loop as follows:

```
library("ncdf")
a <-list.files("D:\\Cloud\\Dropbox\\Documents\\Shared\\", "*", full.names = TRUE)

dt <- as.POSIXct(strptime(basename(a), "data_%Y%m%dT%H%M%S_%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", tz = "GMT"))
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  f <- open.ncdf(a[i])
  A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="Sgf",verbose=TRUE)
  B <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="gh")
  C <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="jk")
  df <- data.frame(date = dt, A, B ,C ) 
  print(df) # For debugging purposes
  if (i==1) {
     write.table(df,file="es55.txt")
     }
  else {
     write.table(df,file="es55.txt", append = TRUE)          
}
```

Otherwise, what is the output of the print(df) statement in each loop run?